# Vue.JS Sending Request Continuously - Websocket

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I initialized new vue.js project by using **vue create project-name**
When I opened up network tab, I saw that system sends request continuously (and so fast) although there is no changes on the page and the system.

I checked other vue.js projects that I created before, there is not this kind of situations. Why is this happening and isn't it harmful ?

https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501507732068

(I can not add this image, if you edit, I would appreciate)

edit: Also I realized that when I change something, normally vue updates itself immediately. Now it does not. When I refresh the page, I can see the changes after that.

edit2: I tried to create 2 vue.js project. You can see the package.json files.

1. **vue create project-name** -> router & vuex -> history yes
2. reinstall vue/cli -> **vue create project-name**

---

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

---

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a websocket, no its not strange. It will poll continuously every X ms. If you use a library like `socket.io` you will see the same behaviour. It's a polling architecture.

Comment: Normally, I did not see this kind of behavior when I created vue project as far as i remember. This is why I was suprised actually. I did not add anything to the project. Only created it. I feel like something is wrong.

Comment: Can you add more info? Like library version, steps done to install it, also the link you pasted is just showing Christmas stuff??